# How do I make page_action appear for specific pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was playing around with some chrome extensions and I found this example:http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url/

Everything works fine, but I want to create my own extension and I want to see the page_action Icon  on a specific site, not ones with 'g' in their urls.
So I tried simply to change the script from this:

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
// If the letter 'g' is found in the tab's URL...
if (tab.url.indexOf('g') > -1) {
// ... show the page action.
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Into this:

```
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
```

But now it doesn't work...
I don't get it. Obviously I can use a workaround, but that's not the point... First of all, must I create a background page to do this? I think yes but I can't see why, and why the .show method doesn't work alone?
I tried to search in the google documentation and stuff, but I couldn't find anything useful  I'm no expert and this has been my first afternoon spent on google extension, but how should I know that the "chrome.page.show(tabId)" must go in a background page if it's not written anywhere? No intent to criticize, but how the hell did you guys find out? All chrome methods must go in a background page?
Well, definitely much more questions then what its legit. Hope you can give me at least one answer!

Comment: Are you giving it a valid `tabId`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html
...says...

> By default, a page action is hidden. When you show it, you specify the
>   tab in which the icon should appear. The icon remains visible until
>   the tab is closed or starts displaying a different URL (because the
>   user clicks a link, for example).

So even if your tabid was valid it would dissapear pretty quick as your only running `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);` once when the background page first gets run.
You need to check for changes to tabs in the background constantly because pageactions dont have matches/exclude_matches settings in the manifest like content scripts do (pity).  So you have to check yourself and respond to changes.
If you want it to work for a specific site just change it to something like...

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // If the tabs url starts with "http://specificsite.com"...
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http://specificsite.com') == 0) {
        // ... show the page action.
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. I read that passage you quoted, but apparently I didn't understand it that well!

Comment: Mmh, you can answer to this question too:
Assuming bg.js is the file which contains (and contains **only**) the code I quoted (or the one you quoted). Why if I write this: <script src="bg.js"></script> in the background.html it does work, but if I try to write the code directly in background.html it doesn't?

Comment: My guess is that you have `"manifest_version": 2` in your manifest file, which will disallow inline <script> blocks...http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html  ..so either either use `<script src="bg.js"></script>` in a background.html, or remove the `"manifest_version": 2` in your manifest, or change the background part of the manifest too `"background": { "scripts": ["bg.js"] }`...didnt know you could do the last one till just now.

Comment: And again you're damn right. Thank you very much! I'm glad you found out something new while answering to me, so it wasn't a complete waste of time for you! :D

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a way to handle subdomains, if you have a site with a subdomain such as **blog.specificsite.com**, or need to use wildcards, you can also use regex in this format

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
{
    if(typeof tab != "undefined" && typeof tab != "null" )
    {
        // If the tabs URL contains "specificsite.com"...
        //This would work in the same way as *specificsite.com*, with 0 or more characters surrounding the URL.
        if (/specificsite[.]com/.test(tab.url)) 
        {
            // ... show the page action.
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        }
    }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

to match the substring within the URL. It also helps with computation to do a null/undefined check to avoid additional exception handling.