# extension programming: where should the logic and dynamic behavior exist? background js, content_script, popup js

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension that does the following:

1. have a pageaction or browseraction (not sure which one is more appropriate).
2. if the url of the page is found in my database/service then allow the Action to have/show a popup where some information from my service is displayed.
3. Otherwise make the Action button look disabled and show no popups

I have been trying a background script with a popup. Have not been able to show contents in the popup set to the results from my service. For the communication between the background and the popup I used the advice here: [How to communicate between popup.js and background.js in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546778/how-to-communicate-between-popup-js-and-background-js-in-chrome-extension) but did not manage to get it worked. and debugging the popup has been almost impossible.

I tried creating an iFrame using content_script in the main page. That did not go well at all. Lots of cross frame exceptions.

Comment: In chrome you can use declarativeContent API in event page to register the URLs for your page action, [example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:declarativecontent).

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't think what I want to do on the URL is achievable using declarativeContent. A service call must be made to determine if the URL qualifies or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for what you're doing you should look at page actions. Page actions are greyed out by default but you can choose to show them.
Having a look at [How do I make page_action appear for specific pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244748/how-do-i-make-page-action-appear-for-specific-pages) you could update it by looping through your list of URLs

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['urls'], function(result) {
        for (var item in result.urls) {
            if (tab.url.indexOf(item) > -1) {
                chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
                //set url to the URL you want for the popup
                chrome.pageAction.setPopup({tabId: tabId, popup: url})
                //or you could create a new window - see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create
            }
        }
    });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Edit: Sorry, I realise now that you're actually trying to debug the popup instead. Hopefully this helps for checking the URL though